# Dragablz TabablzControl Visibility property not working

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, material-design, tabcontrol

I'm using dragablz:TabablzControl in a project of mine and I have the need of hide/show some tabs dinamically.
The fact is the control is not respecting the property Visibility of the TabItem.
I've tried with and without binding, like this:

```
<dragablz:TabablzControl Grid.Row="2" BorderThickness="0" FixedHeaderCount="20">

<TabItem Header="Additional Info" Visibility="{Binding ShowAdditionalInfoTab, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}">
    <controls:AdditionalInfoControl />
</TabItem>

<TabItem Header="Additional Info" Visibility="Collapsed">
    <controls:AdditionalInfoControl />
</TabItem>

</dragablz:TabablzControl>
```

But none is working. Change the "FixedHeaderCount" does not affect the result.

The tab remains always visible.

Is there any other way that I can achieve the result I need?

Comment: "getting tear-able tabs from the TabablzControl is a doddle." I want to doddle them.  In the head.  With a brick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've received a response from the development team, and I'm leaving it here for anyone who has the same problem.

> Yeah, obviously there’s since changes to the standard tab control to support all of the extra features, and currently that’s not supported. You’d have to temporarily remove your hidden item from the source.